# How to get influxdb docker image to initialize graphite and telegraf

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb, initializing

Using the official InfluxDB docker image, I am trying to have multiple databases one that uses Graphite and the other uses the normal InfluxDB.

I am using docker-compose to build and start the images. I am initializing the InfluxDB with a slightly modified version of what is in the docs because I also want Graphite enabled. This all seems to work fine but when I try and run with docker-compose up, I can see it is not opening up 2003 graphite port. My end goal is to get data from netdata and pi-hole and use grafana to graph all that data.

the script to initialize influx:

```
docker run --rm \
    -e INFLUXDB_DB=db0 -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true \
    -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password \
    -e INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=password \
    -e INFLUXDB_GRAPHITE_ENABLED=true \
    -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb \
    influxdb /init-influxdb.sh
```

the docker-compose yaml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
    grafana:
          image: grafana/grafana
          container_name: grafana
          restart: always
          ports:
              - 3000:3000
          networks:
              - monitoring
          volumes:
              - grafana-volume:/var/lib/grafana
    influxdb:
          image: influxdb
          container_name: influxdb
          restart: always
          ports:
              - 8086:8086
              - 2003:2003
          networks:
              - monitoring
          volumes:
              - influxdb-volume:/var/lib/influxdb
    networks:
        monitoring:
    volumes:
        grafana-volume:
            external: true
        influxdb-volume:
            external: true
```

This is the output I get when starting the image.

```
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:50:53.957730Z lvl=info msg="InfluxDB starting" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 version=1.7.3 branch=1.7 commit=698dbc789aff13c2678357a6b93ff73dd7136571
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:50:53.957829Z lvl=info msg="Go runtime" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 version=go1.11 maxprocs=4
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:50:54.059549Z lvl=info msg="Using data dir" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=store path=/var/lib/influxdb/data
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:50:54.059704Z lvl=info msg="Compaction settings" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=store max_concurrent_compactions=2 throughput_bytes_per_second=50331648 throughput_bytes_per_second_burst=50331648
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:50:54.059763Z lvl=info msg="Open store (start)" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=store trace_id=0DQ_IJvl000 op_name=tsdb_open op_event=start
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:50:54.068293Z lvl=info msg="Reading file" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 engine=tsm1 service=cacheloader path=/var/lib/influxdb/wal/_internal/monitor/1/_00001.wal size=10564283
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:00.401835Z lvl=info msg="Reading file" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 engine=tsm1 service=cacheloader path=/var/lib/influxdb/wal/_internal/monitor/1/_00002.wal size=6833556
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.724641Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=store trace_id=0DQ_IJvl000 op_name=tsdb_open index_version=inmem path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/_internal/monitor/1 duration=15659.985ms
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.725095Z lvl=info msg="Open store (end)" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=store trace_id=0DQ_IJvl000 op_name=tsdb_open op_event=end op_elapsed=15665.323ms
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.728132Z lvl=info msg="Opened service" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=subscriber
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.728283Z lvl=info msg="Starting monitor service" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=monitor
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.728352Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=monitor name=build
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.728416Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=monitor name=runtime
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.728471Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=monitor name=network
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.728562Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=monitor name=system
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.728787Z lvl=info msg="Starting precreation service" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=shard-precreation check_interval=10m advance_period=30m
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.729479Z lvl=info msg="Starting snapshot service" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=snapshot
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.729555Z lvl=info msg="Starting continuous query service" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=continuous_querier
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.729043Z lvl=info msg="Storing statistics" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=monitor db_instance=_internal db_rp=monitor interval=10s
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.729642Z lvl=info msg="Starting HTTP service" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=httpd authentication=false
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.729699Z lvl=info msg="opened HTTP access log" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=httpd path=stderr
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.731377Z lvl=info msg="Listening on HTTP" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=httpd addr=[::]:8086 https=false
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.732022Z lvl=info msg="Starting retention policy enforcement service" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000 service=retention check_interval=30m
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.732881Z lvl=info msg="Sending usage statistics to usage.influxdata.com" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000
influxdb    | ts=2019-02-04T20:51:09.733412Z lvl=info msg="Listening for signals" log_id=0DQ_IJXG000
```

Comment: Strange to see you booting up the `influx` container using the `docker`binary and not the `docker-compose` script.

Comment: I am starting influxdb with docker-compose, that script is run once to initialize a default influx database on the storage volume.

Comment: did you ever get this working?